# What happens when WO.FLOWCONTROLLED is enabled?

Tags: maximo

*MAXIMO Asset Management (MAM) version: 7.6.1.2:*

In Work Order Tracking, I can enable flow control on a work order (WO.FLOWCONTROLLED=1).

I'm trying to figure out what happens behind the scenes when flow control is enabled -- so that I can understand how it might impact other processes (i.e. wokflow). For example, by doing some random tests, I've observed that it does the following:

1. WO can't be changed to complete until all tasks are complete
2. When the user completes all tasks, the WO automatically changes to complete

It's possible that it does other things too -- but I have no way of knowing.

I can't find any specific information in the documentation about what actually happens when WO.FLOWCONTROLLED=1. I've also asked IBM support, but haven't gotten a clear answer there either.

---

What happens when WO.FLOWCONTROLLED is enabled?

Comment: Just to let you know this question is probably not a good fit for StackOverflow (generally intended for programming related questions) and might be best asked somewhere like the IBM Maximo Community. https://community.ibm.com/community/user/communities/community-home/digestviewer?communitykey=3d7261ae-48f7-481d-b675-a40eb407e0fd&tab=digestviewer

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help clarify how the Flow Control Feature works and is configured in Maximo:

[Understanding and Configuring Maximo’s Flow Control Feature](https://interprosoft.com/maximotimes/maximo/tips-tricks/understanding-and-configuring-maximos-flow-control-feature/)

Comment: @user1973 - If the answer I provided was useful please consider accepting it - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow